# javascript function not being called/not working from html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

This is my whole html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title> text conversion</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function testResults(form)
{

var str = form.stringn.value;

str.split(" ");
document.write("testing1");
var length = str.length;
var newn = "";

for(var i = 0; i<length; i++)
{
    if(str[i].charAt(str[i].length - 1) != ".")
    {
        str[i] = str[i] + ".";
    }
    str[i] = str[i] + " ";
    str[i].charAt(0) = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    newn = newn + str[i];

}
document.write(newn);
document.write("testing");
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="stringform" action="" method="get">
Text: <input type="text" name="stringn"><br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" Value="convert" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

The html is being displayed correctly, but the button does not produce any action. I even tried document.write("testing") below the loop in the javascript, which had no effect, which makes me think the function is not being called at all. The idea of the function is to format the input string to capitalise the first letter of each word, and put a period after each word.

This is my first time trying to use javascript, so possibly I'm doing something wrong that should be obvious?

final solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> text conversion</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function testResults(form)
{

var str = form.stringn.value;

var strn = str.split(" ");

var length = strn.length;
var newn = "";

for(var i = 0; i<length; i++)
{

    if(strn[i].charAt(strn[i].length - 1) != ".")
    {
        strn[i] = strn[i] + ".";
    }
    strn[i] = strn[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strn[i].slice(1);

    strn[i] = strn[i] + " ";
    newn = newn + strn[i];


}
document.write(newn);

}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="stringform" action="" method="get">
Text: <input type="text" name="stringn"><br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" Value="convert" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You are also using ``new`` as a variable. New is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in javascript. I would suggest running your code through [js hint](http://www.jshint.com/) or another linter to check for syntax errors.

Comment: Open up your browser console, and you'll see *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new*

Comment: the `<script>` language attribute is deprecated, use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: fixed it and a couple of other things I spotted, but still not working

Comment: You might need to change language="javascript" to type="text/javascript" as well. Using "new" as a variable is a big no-no though.

Comment: What even is `strn`? Is this the actual code? Do you have a browser with a JS console? What do expect `document.write` to do after the document has already been written?

Comment: @fonduman, did you try my solution below?

Comment: I don't see your answer. 
I've just did document.write before the loop and it works. I think there's something in the loop that must stop it completing.

Comment: Updated with fixed code, testing1 is printing out but nothing else is

Comment: You can debug javascript using the console in most browsers. Your error is occuring at `str[i].charAt(0) = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();`  You can't set `charAt()` @njenson seems to have a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. Also, echoing The comments before about using new as a variable.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> text conversion</title>
<script language="JavaScript">

function testResults(form)
{
    var str = form.stringn.value;
    var newString = "";
    var strList = str.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < strList.length; i++){
        newWord = strList[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strList[i].slice(1) + ".";       
        newString += newWord + " ";
    }
    document.write(newString);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="stringform" action="" method="get">
Text: <input type="text" name="stringn"><br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" Value="convert" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: ah, that seemed to be the final piece, although I didn't use it exactly like that, because I don't want to add on a period if it already has a period. Final code shall be edited in in question.

Answer (score 2):

Set `<script type="text/javascript">` in your `<head>`!